# Export High chart to power point

Tags: highcharts

I am using the high charts.And these all have the buttons for export to .PDF and images on each chart.i want to a another button apart from these buttons.When I click on this button, it export all the high chart in single **Powerpoint** . And my whole code in c#

Comment: Right. Any work so far?

Comment: not yet , doing investigation

Answer (score 1):

At this moment export for ppt/pptx is not available, but you can prepare your own exporting server and prepare this functionality, based on SVG. Manual [here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server)

I advice to vote for this concept in our uservoice [here](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/1172567-powerpoint-export)